# Farseer physics engine documentation

Tags: c#, .net, xna, farseer

is there any great documentation of the farseer 2D physics engine ?
i really need in an XNA 2D game

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In [their own documentation](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation), they write:

> We include the same features as Box2D, you can [view their manual here](http://box2d.org/manual.html)

Which actually points to a rather decent manual in my opinion.